# Zend Framework 1 app inside Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework

I'm thinking of migrating a fairly large web app from Zend Framework 1 to Symfony 2. This will need to be done in a way as to allow maintenance and feature additions to the ZF1 app, so I thought that a good way forward would be to embed the ZF1 app within a Symfony2 project so that I can then slowly move functionality from one to the other.

My question is how to go about this sensibly. To prove that the concept would work I've modified the call to `$kernel->handle()` in `app.php` so that exceptions are not caught, and then I've caught `NotFoundHttpException` and used that to invoke the ZF front controller (see the code below), but this feels like a horrible hack. What's the better way to achieve this?

```
   app_dev.php:

   ...
   try {
      $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
      $kernel->loadClassCache();
      $request  = Request::createFromGlobals();
      $response = $kernel->handle($request, null, false); // Don't handle exceptions
      $response->send();
      $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
   } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
      require_once 'index.php'; // Dispatch ZF1 app
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a nicer solution by doing something along the lines of what's described here: http://marcjschmidt.de/blog/2013/11/30/symfony-custom-dynamic-router.html, i.e. by implementing a custom event handler for `kernel.request` that delegates to the ZF1 app if a route isn't found.

It still works by catching the `NotFoundHttpException`, but isn't quite such a hack.

Is there a better way to delegate to the ZF1 app when routes aren't found by Symfony2 than by catching an exception? Using an exception as a switch condition doesn't seem very nice.